# Enumerate system drives in nodejs

Tags: node.js, windows

Is there a way to retrieve the drive name of all logical drives on a computer ?

I've looked at the fs api, but from there I can only enumerate the files and directories of a given directory.

Comment: which system are you targeting? Does the solution need to work cross platform or can it be platform specific?

Comment: I'm targeting windows and it does not need to be cross platform

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "drive name". If you mean drives in the form of `\\.\PhysicalDriveN`, I faced the same problem and implemented this module that works in all major operating systems:

https://github.com/resin-io/drivelist

For Windows, you get information such as:

```
[
    {
        device: '\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE0',
        description: 'WDC WD10JPVX-75JC3T0',
        size: '1000 GB'
    },
    {
        device: '\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE1',
        description: 'Generic STORAGE DEVICE USB Device',
        size: '15 GB'
    }
]
```

Comment: This is the correct and cross-platform solution! If you create an app in nodejs only for one OS, you're doing it wrong!

Comment: If you are failing to build during `npm install drivelist`, just install an older version of this library.

Comment: im getting this error when trying to retrieve the drives: `This version of Node.js requires NODE_MODULE_VERSION 75`. any idea what to do? ive already tried rebuilding and reinstalling

Comment: Contains a lot of nice info, but not the drive label, which is how I am trying to identify a specific removable media...

Answer (score 9):

Based on [Edwin Lee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4824331/edwin-lee)s answer:

```
const child = require('child_process');

child.exec('wmic logicaldisk get name', (error, stdout) => {
    console.log(
        stdout.split('\r\r\n')
            .filter(value => /[A-Za-z]:/.test(value))
            .map(value => value.trim())
    );
});
```

Output: `['C:', 'D:']` etc.

Answer (score 8):

If you targeting on Windows, you could try this:

This solution base upon the idea from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622758/list-partitions-in-nodejs).

I wrap it with promise.

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn

function listDrives(){
    const list  = spawn('cmd');

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        list.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
            // console.log('stdout: ' + String(data));
            const output =  String(data)
            const out = output.split("\r\n").map(e=>e.trim()).filter(e=>e!="")
            if (out[0]==="Name"){
                resolve(out.slice(1))
            }
            // console.log("stdoutput:", out)
        });

        list.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
            // console.log('stderr: ' + data);
        });

        list.on('exit', function (code) {
            console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
            if (code !== 0){
                reject(code)
            }
        });

        list.stdin.write('wmic logicaldisk get name\n');
        list.stdin.end();
    })
}

listDrives().then((data) => console.log(data))
```

Test it, you will see the result like:

```
["c:", "d:"]
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using the [DiskPart](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766465%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) command? Does running `diskpart list` in the command line give you the output you need? If so you can execute this in node using **child_process.exec**

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec
var cmd = 'diskpart list'
exec(cmd, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('error running diskpart list command')
        console.log(err)
        return
    }
    console.log('stdout data')
    console.log(stdout)

    console.log('stderr data')
    console.log(stderr)
})
```

Comment: That would work yes, but I'd like to avoid running a child process and parsing the command output. But that would be probably what I'll resort to if there's nothing in node's API...

Comment: I believe this is the best you are going to do. node.js doesn't have any way to do this natively. On OSX you could read the `/Volumes/` directory and on linux you could look at `/mnt` but Windows doesn't provide a directory of mounted drives for you. Also note http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000854.htm#2 and wmic logicaldisk get name

Answer (score 0):

+1 for @Bagherani's downgrade suggestion!

I am using Electron React Boilerplate v4.0 and could not get drivelist to load. I downgraded to drivelist@5.2.12 and it works for my needs.