# Detect All Top-Level Directories

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, filesystems, fs

What I'd like to do is detect all of the top-level directories (i.e. `C:\`, `A:\`, `X:\`, et cetera) on Windows in light of the fact that `This PC` is seemingly inaccessible.

The following code works, but is obviously not ideal and has many drawbacks. For instance, I don't believe the namespace is even limited to `A` to `Z`, which would create major problems with such an approach.

```
const
  fs = require('fs'),
  ab = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('')

ab.forEach(v => fs.existsSync(`${v}:\\`))
```

Is anybody aware of any other way to do this?

Comment: Google gives me [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-drive-letters).

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/drivelist - OS agnostic

Comment: @KenY-N thanks ill check it out.

Comment: @KenY-N - That google package executes `wmic logicaldisk get caption` in a child_process and uses those results.

Comment: @jfriend00 i was looking at the source code on github and noticed that. is that not a good thing? all this stuff is new to me

Comment: @JaromandaX -  https://www.npmjs.com/package/drivelist supports multiple operating systems via native code, and thus requires compiling.  It does appear to support mac, windows and linux.  It's really more that it supports multiple OSes than it's OS agnostic.

Comment: It's OK to call a child_process to execute a built-in app as long as you know that app is properly installed and in the path (or know where to find it).  The only vulnerability if you're not passing any user-specified stuff into the child_process is if someone somehow messes with the OS and replaces the program `wmic` with something else.  If they can do that, however, they could also be messing with your node.js app in more nefarious ways.

Comment: @jfriend00 ok then are you aware of any safe and efficient ways to identify all of the root directories on a given PC?

Comment: I am not aware of any ways other than the two already-posted options.  FYI, in Windows, the proper term would not be "root directories", but more something like "mounted volumes" or in some cases just "drives", though there can be a top level mounted volume that does not have a drive letter assigned so it's not really a drive.

Comment: All the solutions listed here [Enumerate system drives in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15878969/enumerate-system-drives-in-nodejs) and [List disk partitions in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622758/list-partitions-in-nodejs) all use similar techniques to the ones already listed here.  Lots of other command line choices here: [How to get list of drivers letters](https://serverfault.com/questions/62578/how-to-get-a-list-of-drive-letters-on-a-system-through-a-windows-shell-bat-cmd) and these would also all require child_process.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this if you're okay with using child_process:

```
const child = require('child_process');

child.exec('wmic logicaldisk get name', (error, stdout) => {
    const drives = stdout.split('\r\r\n')
        .filter(value => /[A-Za-z]:/.test(value))
        .map(value => value.trim())

    //do stuff with drives
});
```

`drives` will be an array of available drives like ['C:', ...]

Comment: i will look into this. does using `child_process` introduce vulnerabilities or why would i not be okay using it?

Comment: As long as you use it like this there is no real drawback. The main thing to keep in mind is that you don't want to allow command injection when using it. In this case, we've hardcoded the command, so it can't be exploited in any way.

Comment: ok cool. i should be getting some free time to test everything within the week. ill let u know how it goes. thanks again

Comment: beautiful. what is all of that other info that it spits out in cmd? also, to see if i understand whats happening, it basically opens up a shell to execute the OS command, and then returns whatever, correct?

Comment: For me stdout is just `Name\nC:\nD:\nE:`. Yeah it spawns a child process with a shell and executes the provided commands in that shell, then pipes back the output as stdout :)

Comment: yeah, but i forewent including the `filter` method to not only see what i was dealing with, but also to avoid maybe filtering out drives that do exist but dont exist in that given namespace

Comment: yeah when i console.log(stdout) that is the unfiltered response from my shell

Comment: this may be a dumb question but this only works on windows because its a windows shell command correct?

Comment: Actually child_process itself would work on any platform, this example in particular only works in windows because we are executing windows based commands “wmic”

Comment: yah ok thats what i meant/thought. thanks again mike